# Insights API returns only 7 fields for some posts, 31 for others?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, missing-data

I have two otherwise identical posts on a Facebook page that I administer. One post we'll call "full" returns the full range of insight values (31) I'd expect *even when the values are zero*, while the other which we'll call "subset" returns only a very limited subset of values (7). See below for the actual values returned.

Note that I've confirmed this is the case by using both the GUI-driven export to Excel and the Facebook Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

My first thought was that the API suppresses certain values such as post_negative_feedback if they are zero (i.e., nobody has clicked hide or report as spam/abusive), but this is not the case. The "full" post has no such reports (or at the very least the return value for all the post_negative_* fields are zero.

I've even tried intentionally reporting the post with no negative return values as spam, and then repulling what I thought was a real-time field (i.e., post_negative_feedback), but data still comes back empty:

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  (paging data)
}
```

What gives?

Here is the more limited subset returned for the problematic post:

```
post_engaged_users 
post_impressions 
post_impressions_fan 
post_impressions_fan_unique 
post_impressions_organic 
post_impressions_organic_unique 
post_impressions_unique
```

And here is the full set returned for most other posts (with asterisks added to show the subset returned above):

```
post_consumptions 
post_consumptions_by_type 
post_consumptions_by_type_unique 
post_consumptions_unique 
*post_engaged_users
*post_impressions
post_impressions_by_story_type 
post_impressions_by_story_type_unique 
*post_impressions_fan
post_impressions_fan_paid 
post_impressions_fan_paid_unique 
*post_impressions_fan_unique
*post_impressions_organic 
*post_impressions_organic_unique 
post_impressions_paid 
post_impressions_paid_unique 
*post_impressions_unique 
post_impressions_viral 
post_impressions_viral_unique 
post_negative_feedback 
post_negative_feedback_by_type 
post_negative_feedback_by_type_unique 
post_negative_feedback_unique 
post_stories 
post_stories_by_action_type 
post_story_adds 
post_story_adds_by_action_type 
post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique 
post_story_adds_unique 
post_storytellers 
post_storytellers_by_action_type
```

The issue (besides "why does this happen?") is that I've tried giving negative feedback to the post that fails to report any count whatsoever for this -- and I still receive no data (would expect "1" or something around there). I started out waiting the obligatory 15 minutes (real-time field) and then when that didn't work give it a full 24 hours. What gives?

Comment: Do you have any actual problem you want to discuss?

Comment: Yes, this appears to be a bug. I've tried flagging it as negative and re-pulling (>15 mins later because it's a real-time field) and still get nothing returned on the problematic post.